# Spring boot: Rest Api full response in JSON

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Can we have full response which includes `headers`, `response code` etc in JSON along with body in `spring boot`. e.g

```
{
  "customerLevel": "BETA",
  "responseCode" : 200
}
```

Comment: could you post the part of code with the response object? The controller and method annotations?

Comment: Every response contains headers and a status code. I'm not sure what you want to know.